# Can I organize my figures in separate .tex files and insert them into my main document?

Tags: editors, code, sourcecode

I'm writing a long paper, I have to add many figures, and the code lines for adding all those figures in my paper makes the code hard to read.

Is there a way to for example create a figure1.tex ... figure20.tex, and then just insert them into my main paper to look cleaner?

Comment: What do you mean by `adding all those figures in my paper makes the code hard to read.` exactly what are these figures?

Comment: If the figures are tex codes as well (like tikz figures), you can use `\input{figure1.tex}` (maybe `\include{figure2.tex}` also, sometimes) to integrate them. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/146828) might put in some highlight.

Comment: Thank you @ParthaD. for the insight.

Answer (score 4):

You asked,

> Is there a way to for example create a `figure1.tex` ... `figure20.tex`, and then just insert them into my main paper?

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer: Yes. First, create the files `figure1.tex` thru `figure<n>.tex` -- where `<n>` could be `20` -- with the following overall format:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
% insert relevant code here
\end{figure}
```

Second, use `\input` directives in the main tex file to load them in the desired locations, say,

```
...
\input figure1
...
```

Note that it's *not* necessary to specify the `.tex` extension or to encase the file name in curly braces (a la `\input{figure1}`).

---

That said, what you should probably be doing as well is to find an editor that enables [code folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding), i.e., an editor that has the ability to selectively hide and display -- "fold" -- portions of the file you're currently editing. Among these code portions could be the preamble of a LaTeX document, entire sections (i.e., starting at a `\section` directive and running to just before the next `\section` directive), entire environments such as `table`, `figure`, `theorem`, `lstlisting`, `comment` etc, and so on. Modern editors can easily provide *hierarchical* or *nested* code folding. E.g., you may choose to "fold away" the code that pertains to a lengthy `tabular` environment inside a `table` environment.

A serious benefit of using an editor that can provides code folding is that there's no longer a need to maintain lots of secondary files just for the sake of keeping things tidy and manageable; all code portions can be folded away or  "unfolded" while being kept in a single file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mico. Exactly what i wanted. much appreciated.

Comment: +1 is it worth mentioning the standalone bundle?

Comment: @cmhughes - I'm not sure that the `standalone` bundle does what the OP is trying to achieve. AFAICT, he/she isn't looking to create separate output files. Instead, the objective appears to be to declutter the input file. Naturally, my interpretation may be incorrect.

Comment: That makes sense :)